# Prinicple Volume Node not affecting sides of extruded plane

Tags: materials, shader-nodes

I'm new to Blender and trying to follow this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s9RQ83BKcyI

When I get to 17:44 where he adds the Principle Volume Node, its only affecting the top of my ocean "cube" and not the sides as well, as seen in the tutorial. I have tried starting the entire project over, but it still is not working. Any help would be much appreciated. I have attached my blender file, as well as some screenshots.

[image: Sides of the ocean are not affected the same as top]

[image: My node setup]

My Ocean.blend file:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QCjD4JYeoblY3XBNWG7-KX9awWeYL_Tr/view?usp=share_link

Comment: It might be worth checking to see if the normals were generated correctly

Comment: Thank you! Your comment gave me the idea to just play around in the Normals tab in edit mode and it somehow works now!